# Selecting only first level element, not child elements with the same element name

Tags: jquery, css

How would I select **only the first** level .block and not any of the children?

`$('.block:not("Children of this here")')` <--

```
<div class="block"> <!-- this -->
  <div class="block"> <!-- not this -->
    <div class="block"> <!-- not this -->

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="block"> <!-- and this -->
  <div class="block"> <!-- not this -->
    <div class="block"> <!-- not this -->

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are giving them all a class of `block`? If it's for setting styles on all of them, do you know about inheritance and multiple selectors, i.e. (`.block, .date, .info { color: blue; }`)

Comment: @alex, for this situation let's say renaming the blocks is just not possible (Thanks, Drupal). Thus, the difficulty of this problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If that sample markup has a parent element, for example below. If not, the parent will be `body` if it is valid HTML.

### HTML

```
<div id="parent">
<div class="block">
  <div class="block">
    <div class="block">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

### jQuery

```
$('#parent > .block').css({ border: '1px solid red' });
```

Comment: yay for reasonable solutions!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `:first` selector to select only the first matching `.block` element:

```
$('.block:first')
```

This works because jQuery matches elements in document order.  The outermost `.block` element will be the first element matched by `.block`, and `:first` will filter to only return it.

Note that `:first` is not the same as `:first-child`.

**EDIT**: In response to your update, you can write the following, which will only work if all of the elements are nested three deep:

```
$('.block:note(:has(.block .block))')
```

You can write a more robust solution using a function call:

```
$('.block').not(function() { return $(this).closest('.block').length; })
```

This will find all `.block` elements, then remove any matched elements that have an ancestor matching `.block`.  (You can replace `closest` with `parent` if you want to).

Comment: Sorry I updated the question.. I need to match the first .block of each nest of blocks, so I don't know if this will work since it finds the very first block in the doc

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#parent').children('.block');
```

See [.children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/) jQuery reference.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("div.block:first").<what you want to do>
```

edit: removed the spaces. thanks :-)....now it should be good.

HTH

Comment: You still have an extra space there, unless the `.block` is a child of a `div` element.