# Selecting only the first-level elements for .delegate()

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

How do I only select the first level of children of an element when using `.delegate()`?

Say, I have the following HTML:

```
<div id="list">
  <div>Item 1<div>Item 1-1</div></div>
  <div>Item 2</div>
  <div>Item 3</div>
</div>
```

When I do `$('#list').delegate('div', 'click', function(e) {})`, the element `<div>Item 1-1</div>` would be included (right?) in the handler. How do I only select the first-level child elements for `#list` with this method then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the following to only select direct children:

```
$('#list').delegate('#list > div', 'click', function(e) {});
```

Comment: ha, too easy! I thought the selector inside `delegate` would only select from, and excluding, the previous selector. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

you will got solution here i think .if my guess correct

[Selecting only first level element, not child elements with the same element name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604463/selecting-only-first-level-element-not-child-elements-with-the-same-element-name)

Comment: Thanks for contributing, but that's not exactly what I asked for.