# select only 1st level of nested elements

Tags: jquery

We have the following html:

```
<div>
<div class="bord" id="1">
    parent1
    <div class="bord">
        child1
        <div class="bord">
            subchild1
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
-----------
<span>
<div class="bord" id="2">
    parent1
    <div class="bord">
        child1
        <div class="bord">
            subchild1
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</span>
```

need to have function that will select with call

```
a=$('.bord').new_function();
```

only elements marked in sample as id="1" and id="2";
if after that:

```
b=a.new_function();
```

it should select child1s only

```
b.new_function();
```

should be able to select subchild1s

I tried several ways and have no ideas now.

Comment: So you want some functions to narrow down your selection?Or just selectors?

Comment: please refer this link below.

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604463/selecting-only-first-level-element-not-child-elements-with-the-same-element-name][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604463/selecting-only-first-level-element-not-child-elements-with-the-same-element-name


Thanks.

Comment: I want selector, that select only 1st slice or function that reduce selects, no matter what

Comment: Solved: Thanks Chandresh for vector
http://jsfiddle.net/H7f85/10/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved  myself: http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/3pGXv/

HTML:

```
<div>
    <div class="bord">
        parent1
        <div class="b2">
            b2
        <div class="bord">
            child1
            <div class="bord">
                subchild1
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

-----------
<div>
<div class="b2">
    b2
    <div class="bord">
        parent1
        <div class="bord">
            child1
            <div class="b2">
                b2
                <div class="bord">
                     subchild1
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
​
```

JS:

```
jQuery.fn.firstlevel = function(sel) {
    var obj = $(this);
    if (obj.selector != sel) {
        obj = obj.find(sel);
    }
    obj = obj.not(obj.find(sel));
    console.log(obj);
    return obj;
}
$('.bord')
    .firstlevel('.bord').css('border', '3px solid red')
    .firstlevel('.bord').css('border', '3px solid green')
    .firstlevel('.bord').css('border', '3px solid blue');
$('.b2')
    .firstlevel('.b2').css('border', '1px solid red')
    .firstlevel('.b2').css('border', '1px solid green')
    .firstlevel('.b2').css('border', '1px solid blue');
​
css:

    .bord
    {
        border: 1px solid black;
        margin: 10px;
    }
```

Comment: mark it as answer please, even if it's your post it's helpful

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
//Select first level divs, no matter what is the type of root
divsFirstLevel = $('*').children('div.bord');
$(divsFirstLevel).css('border', '1px solid blue');
//Select first child divs
var firstChild = $(divsFirstLevel).children('div.bord').css('border', '1px solid red');
//Select secondchild divs
var secondChild = $(firstChild).children('div.bord').css('border', '1px solid yellow');
```

Fiddle here; http://jsfiddle.net/ULekd/3/

EDIT - i modified my answer so that it's just selectors:

Comment: sorry, I need for N levels of possible childs.
i trying make it there:
http://jsfiddle.net/H7f85/4/

Comment: What do you mean N levels?You want a function that selects only the first child?

Comment: I need function that select only 1st slice of elements by selector, after second call 2nd and etc

Comment: And why .children() is not what you are looking for?

Comment: because elements can be in different branches of dom. i solved it myself, only thing i not like now it is that i need to use selector twice while call. http://jsfiddle.net/H7f85/9/

Comment: your solution select all children of given element, please compare 
http://jsfiddle.net/ULekd/5/ and  http://jsfiddle.net/H7f85/16/ (i chnaged colors and places same test html as at mine current solution)
the initial idea was to use such function to add events, so elements should be touched only once

Answer (score 0):

You have to give them a different class name. Its logically impossible to select the `parent-child-subchild` with the same name and element type.

So I would prefer that you must assign differnet name.

```
<div>
<div class="parent-bord" id="1">
    parent1
    <div class="child-bord">
        child1
        <div class="subchild-bord">
            subchild1
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
-----------
<span>
<div class="parent-bord" id="2">
    parent1
    <div class="child-bord">
        child1
        <div class="subchild-bord">
            subchild1
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</span>
```

So to select Parent you can do.

```
$('div.parent-bord').each(...);
```

OR

```
$('div.parent-bord#1'); //--> First parent.
```

After u get the parent you can get their child in the same way

```
$('div.parent-bord#1').children('div.child-bord'); // It will select the child div.
```

Comment: task is to have not different tag names, it can be 
`<div><div><div></div></div></div>`
or `<span><span><span></span></span></span>`, anything

Answer (score 0):

You can take the number of parent elements that the first `.bord` element has and then filter the other `.bord` elements keeping only those which have the same number of parent elements.

```
var bord = $(".bord");
var parentsLength = bord.first().parents().length;
var firstLevelBord = bord.filter(function () {
    return $(this).parents().length === parentsLength;
});
// firstLevelBord contains all the first level .bord elements
```

Then you can use the `.children` to filter the second level .bord elements, third level and so on.

```
var secondLevelBord = firstLevelBord.children(".bord");
var thirdLevelBord = secondLevelBord.children(".bord");
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/silviubogan/W8NYn/23/

This could be easily implemented as a jQuery plugin.