# How to style top-level elements of a nested list

Tags: jquery, styling, nested-lists

Given the following unorderd, nested list structure:

```
<ul id="nestedList">
    <li>
        Item A
        <ul>
            <li>Item A Descrip</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        Item B
        <ul>
            <li>Item B Descrip</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        Item C
        <ul>
            <li>Item C Descrip</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

What jQuery selector do I need to use to only style the top-level li elements (Item A, Item B, etc) and not the "Descrip" li elements?

I tried working with the .children() selector, which the jQuery documentation says only selects the immediate children of the selected element, but everything I tried either styled the entire list or only the second level li elements.

Here's the jQuery I was working with:

```
$('#nestedList').children().css('font-weight', 'bold');
```

and:

```
$('ul#nestedList').children().css('font-weight', 'bold');
```

**UPDATE**
I created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eventide/Xg4bj/) for this, so feel free to mess with that...

Comment: may you need same as my own question ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6729770/select-only-1st-level-of-nested-elements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *"but everything I tried either styled the entire list"*

This is because your styles placed on the top level are being inherited from the styles of the top level.

You need to override those styles on the nested lists.

```
$('#nestedList').children().css('font-weight', 'bold')
                .find('li').css('font-weight','normal');
```

**Working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/w66rK/

Comment: @eventide: They *do* only select the first level children. But you can't stop the fact that some CSS styles are passed from parent to child via inheritance. This doesn't have anything to do with your DOM selection via jQuery. Even if you don't have *any* JavaScript, but only use styles in your stylesheet, you'll have the same issue. Styles placed on the top level `<li>` elements will be inherited by their ancestors.

Comment: ...imagine if this wasn't the case. If you just wanted to change the font on your page, you'd need to select *every* element on the page and style them individually. Thank goodness that some of the style properties *do* inherit, so you'd only need to style to root of the document.

Comment: I removed my comment after you edited your answer! :) Sorry. I understand now that inheritance is causing the whole thing to be styled. Thanks for the explanation and CORRECT answer! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('#nestedList > li').css('font-weight', 'bold');
```

Comment: `$('#nestedList > li')` is identical to using `$('#nestedList').children()` like he's doing in the question.

Comment: @evantide: Yes, that's my point. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6765285/how-to-style-top-level-elements-of-a-nested-list/6765368#6765368) for an explanation and fix.

Answer (score 1):

Using direct CSS would be easiest:

```
#nestedList > li {
    /* direct li descendants of the parent ul */
    /* CSS */
}
```

The same selector, of course, works with jQuery:

```
$('#nestedList > li').css('color','red'); // etc...
```

Comment: `$('#nestedList > li')` is identical to using `$('#nestedList').children()` like he's doing in the question.

Comment: Hm, I knew that the end-result would be identical; I was unaware that the underlying behaviour would be identical, though. Thanks for the heads-up. =)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#nestedList > li')
```

http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/

Comment: `$('#nestedList > li')` is identical to using `$('#nestedList').children()` like he's doing in the question.