# How to get only first level divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have a div with an id of `content` and I want to get the `id` of the first level `div` elements, eg. `box1`, `box2`, `box3`. How can this be done ?

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="box1" class="box1class">
        <div>...</div>
    </div>
    <div id="box2" class="box1class">
        <div>...</div>
    </div>
    <div id="box3" class="box1class">
        <div>...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Selecting only first level element, not child elements with the same element name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604463/selecting-only-first-level-element-not-child-elements-with-the-same-element-nam)

Comment: Why do you need the IDs? Please tell me it's not so you can say `$('#' + id)`

Comment: @Sorpigal I wouldn't be surprised. The amount of redundant code people write with jQuery is mind-boggling...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `>` child seelctor.

```
var ids = [];
$("#content > div").each(function() {
    ids.push(this.id);
});
```

You could shorten this further by using `map()`:

```
var ids = $("#content > div").map(function() {
    return this.id;
}).get();
```

Comment: Thx Rory, misunderstood the question :-P deleted my silly comment :)

Answer (score 5):

```
$("#content > div")
```

Like this. You can get array of div's like this

```
   var array =  $("#content > div").map(function(){
       return this.id;
    }).get();
```

See in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/DsyzV/

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
$("#content > div").each(function() {
  var divId = this.id;
});
```

Comment: This is misleading answer. $("#content > div").attr("id") gets only first div's id, not all.